# observeEvent and RHandsontable

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, rhandsontable

I want to perform reactivity with RHandsontable in shiny, which would take input from a table and perform calculations. However, there's an error happening with hot_to_r. But for the life of me, I can't see what the problem is, because this has worked before for me. I get the error:

```
Warning: Error in genColHeaders: Change no recognized:afterChange
```

Here is the code:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "App"),
  dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
  dashboardBody(skin = "blue",
  box(
    rHandsontableOutput("tt"),
    actionButton(inputId = "sim", label = "Simulate")
  ),
  box(
    tableOutput("result"),
    span(textOutput("error"), style="color:red")
    )
  )
)

server <-  function(input, output, session){

    tt <- matrix(as.integer(c(10, 20, 30, 40)), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)

    output$tt <- renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(tt, readOnly = FALSE))

    observeEvent( input$sim, {

      tt_input <- hot_to_r(input$tt)

      result <- tryCatch(
       {
        log(tt_input)
       }, warning = function(w){
           return(w$message)
       }, error = function(e){
           return(e$message)
         }
       )

      if(!is(result, "character")){
        output$result <- renderTable(result, rownames = TRUE)
        output$error <- renderText("")
      } else {
        output$error <- renderText({
               result
        })
        output$result <- renderTable(matrix())
      }

    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score -1):

I discovered the problem. hot_to_r() must have dataframe input, so the following works

```
tt <- data.frame('col1' = c(10,30), 'col2' = c(20,40))

hot_to_r(tt)
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a solution to your problem? `hot_to_r()` basically pulls the data from an `rhandsontable` object and turns it into a data frame. Passing a data frame directly to the function does not seem like it is something you would want to do.

Comment: Right, it should have output$tt <- renderRHandsontable(rhandsontable(tt, readOnly = FALSE)) where tt in server function environment is a dataframe instead of a matrix. Apologies for the messy variable naming

Comment: Okay I understand better. Thank you.